# performSegueWithIdentifier outside of viewDidAppear not working

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, segue

I am sure this is a beginners question, but I am trying to perform a Segue if the users of my application are logged into Facebook, or if they do in the initial screen. In the viewDidAppear function, I test if they are already logged in, and if they are, the segue works just fine. But in my other function, is does absolutely nothing (not even an error).

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    if (PFUser.currentUser() == nil) {
        //...//
    } else {
        print("User already logged in")
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("mainMenuSegue", sender: self) // This one is Working
    }}

func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController, didLogInUser user: PFUser) -> Void {
    print("We just logged you in!")
    if PFUser.currentUser()!["First_Name"] == nil {
        returnUserData() } else {
        print(NSThread.isMainThread()) //Returning True
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("mainMenuSegue", sender: self)// This one is NOT Working
    }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you even calling the method? if so where are you calling it?

Comment: Sorry, but I am teaching myself to code and this might be misguided. But isnt self.performSegueWithIdentifier the call to the method? Its working on the first time I call it (in viewDidAppear) but not inside de loginViewController function

Comment: Yes, ofcourse `performSegueWithIdentifier` will do the function, but the below method that you wrote, where are you calling that?

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 6 and later it´s possible: You have to implement the method in the controller and return true or false

if you return false segue will fail to goto destination.

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
```

in swift

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String!, sender: AnyObject!) -> Bool {
   //todo
}
```

Comment: Hi Zumry, could you kindly clarify? Would you happen to know the equivalent in Swift?